# Adding a Dropdown Select menu to select csv files in highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

Hi I am very new in programming and trying my hand. I am working on a project where i am using highchart. I am using csv file as data source. please take a look at the code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $.get('dhaka.csv', function(csv) {
        // Create the chart
        window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type:'spline'
            },
            data: {
                csv: csv
            },
        }, function(chart) {

        });
    });
});
</script>


</head>
<body>
<select id="selectOpt">
    <option value="dhaka.csv">Dhaka</option>
    <option value="khulna.csv">Khulna</option>
    <option value="maymansingh.csv">Maymanshingh</option>
</select>
<div id="container" style="height: 600px; min-width: 600px; margin-top:10px;"></div>
</body>
```

I will be having multiple csv file and need to have an option to select from a dropdown menu. Hope i have explained properly. Thanks in advance. Your help is appriciated.

I have used parsecsv.lib to read a csv file and my select menu will get the options from that csv. which i have done already. but i need to pass few other values ass well which i can not. please help me on this.. the updated code is here

```
    <?php
        require_once('parsecsv.lib.php');
        $csv = new parseCSV();
        $csv->auto('latlang.csv');
        $num = count($csv->data);
        $numRow = $num-1;
    ?>
    <select id="selectOpt" style="width:200px;">
    <?php 
        for ($x = 0; $x <= $numRow; $x++) {
            $ston= $csv->data[$x]['Station'];
            //$arr = explode(' ',trim($ston));
            echo "<option value=".$ston.">".$ston."</option>";
        }
    ?>  
    </select>
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 600px; margin-top:10px;"></div>
    <p id="demo"></p>

</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {      
     getChart('Amalshid');
});
var getChart = function(strFileName){
    $.get( strFileName + '.csv', function(csv) {
    // I AM STUCK HERE //
    //  data form latlang.csv   
    var locations = <?php print json_encode($csv->data); ?>;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
        var dataz = locations[i]; 
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = strFileName + '<br>' + dataz.Station + '<br>' + dataz.DL + '<br>' + dataz.HRWL;
    }
        // Create the chart
        window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type:'spline'
            },
            data: {
                csv: csv,
                startRow: 34,
                startColumn:3
            },
        }, function(chart) {

        });
    });
};

$("#selectOpt").on("change",function(e){
    getChart($(this).val());
});
```

The csv file looks like this

```
Station,RiverName,Longtitude,Latitude,DL,HRWL,CL
Amalshid,Kushiyara,92.4716,24.8845,15.85,18.28,100
Bahadurabad,B'putra,89.6743,25.0934,19.5,20.62,1
Hardinge.Bridge,Ganges,89.0279,24.072,14.25,15.19,1
```

All I need, when I select from the drop-down menu it will take River name and DL and pass the value. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a function that will create the chart and call it when the select changes. This new function (which I've named 'getChart') will accept the csv file name as an argument and inject it into the $.get. Right now you are only creating the chart once when the document loads.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
     getChart('dhaka.csv');
});

var getChart = function(strFileName){
    $.get(strFileName, function(csv) {
        // Create the chart
        window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type:'spline'
            },
            data: {
                csv: csv
            },
        }, function(chart) {

        });
    });
};

$("#selectOpt").on("change",function(e){
    getChart($(this).val());
});
```

(NOTE: I'm not that familiar with highcharts so I am assuming that that part of your code works. I'm only demonstrating the simple act of passing the value of the Select to another function. If the chart is not being generated that is a separate question.)

Comment: Hi, Your solution did the trick. but now i am stuck somewhere else. I am trying to get the select menu options from another csv file can you help?

Comment: You need to dynamically inject the name of the file into the function. There are many ways to do this. Where is the name of the file coming from? Server code? User input?

Answer (score 0):

So set an event listener on your select element so that on change it gets the selected csv and then uses high charts series.setdata command

You are using highcharts so assuming you have jquery installed

Things you will need:
event binding: https://api.jquery.com/change/

highcharts event reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData